# Spring Data Redis multiple instances

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data

I have 2 instances of Redis Server redis1 and redis2.
I'm trying get Data form redis1 and save data to redis2 with Spring Data Redis support but it's not working. My code:

```
//class a
@Configuration
public class RedisAConfig {
    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        jedisConnectionFactory.setHostName("host1");
        return jedisConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, String>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());

        return redisTemplate;
    }
}

//class b
@Configuration
public class RedisBConfig {
    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        jedisConnectionFactory.setHostName("host2");
        return jedisConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, String>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());

        return redisTemplate;
    }
}

//use class
@EnableConfigurationProperties({RedisAConfig.class, RedisBConfig.class})
public class Receiver {

    @Autowired
    private RedisAConfig redisAConfig;

    @Autowired
    private RedisAConfig redisBConfig;

    private String getUsernameFromRedis(String userIp) {

        return redisBConfig.redisTemplate().opsForValue()..get(userIp);
    }

    private void saveThreatsToRedis(String userIp, List<Log> threats)    {
        JSONSerializer serializer = new JSONSerializer();
        String json = serializer.serialize(threats);
        String key = "TH:" + userIp;
        redisAConfig.redisTemplate().opsForValue().set(key, json);
    }
}
```

When I'm using method getUsernameFromRedis() the host for redis which is used is "host1" not "host2" :-(
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Since it is a single application, you have to have unique `bean names` to populate them all to single `ApplicationContext`. Otherwise only one bean with the same name exists after context startup.

By default `@Bean` populates with the name from the method. That's why you see `host1`, not `host2`.

So, or provide unique names for those bean methods, or use `@Bean(name = )` attribute.

Comment: I tried this by adding unique name for all of these `@Beans` but then Spring throws Exception that can't find `@Bean` with name jedisConnectionFactory()

Comment: One of them can live with just `jedisConnectionFactory()`

Comment: I tried this solution also but it's producing error: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: oldJedisConnectionFactory,jedisConnectionFactory

Comment: In that case you have to use `@Qualifier("jedisConnectionFactory")` alongside with `@Autowired` on the `private RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory` field everywhere.

Comment: If I'm using this: `@Qualifier("redisTemplate")
 private RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate;
 
 @Qualifier("oldRedisTemplate")
 private RedisTemplate<String, String> oldRedisTemplate;` I have same error: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: oldJedisConnectionFactory,jedisConnectionFactory

Comment: Share, please, more StackTrace for that `expected single matching`. There should be a path which your class is impacted

Answer (score 1):

@Autowired
private RedisAConfig redisAConfig;

@Autowired
private **RedisAConfig** redisBConfig;

it should be RedisBConfig.